# When will this generalized binomial model generate an exchangeable sequence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Start with a generalized binomial model

$$P(X_{n+1}=1\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=\theta_n+ n^{-1} d_n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
$$P(X_{n+1}=1)=p_{n+1}=\theta_n + n^{-1}d_n \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$$
$$P(X_1 = 1)= \theta_0$$

With $0\leq \theta_n+ d_n <1$. This generates a random sequence $X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N)$.

I'd like to find appropriate conditions on $(\theta_n)$ and $(d_n)$ so that $X$ is exchangeable.

What kind of techniques can I use to figure this out for a general $N$?

I'd start by testing a hypothesis that we need $(\theta_n),(d_n)$ constant sequences such that $p_m=p = \frac{\theta_n}{1-d_n}=\frac{\theta}{1-d}$ for all $m$, but I can't think of an efficient way to check this beyond some brute force that seems like it will quickly get unwieldy. And within this case, $d=0$ would obviously give exchangeability, but I'd like something nontrivial.

I'd be interested in exchangeability results for other generalizations which allow for dependence between trials as well.

Comment: At the least, I don't think constant $\theta,d$ will get you what you want. Try $\Pr(0,1,1)$ compared with $\Pr(1,1,0)$ with $\theta=d=.25$. The first probability is $(1-\theta_0)(.25)(.25+.125)=(1-\theta_0)(3/32)$. The second is $\theta_0 (.25+.25)(1-.25-.25)=.25\theta_0$. Exchangeability requires $.25\theta_0 = (1-\theta_0)(3/32)$ which is only true if $\theta_0 = 3/11. Then, wouldn't this ruin the identical distribution?